# Weird behaviour with g_signal_connect on GTK

Tags: c, gtk

I'm trying to send a pointer to a structure I created to a function using ***g_signal_connect*** but was getting a segmentation fault. After some testing, I decided to print the pointer's address inside the function that was being called (this function is responsible for drawing on a drawing_area, which means it is called regularly via ***g_timeout_add***) and, alternating, it prints "(nil)" or the correct address. I have no clue what could be causing this.

```
typedef struct{
...
}prog_info

gboolean on_draw_event(GtkWidget  *draw_area  ,
                       cairo_t    *cr         ,
                       prog_info  *info)
{
  printf("\ninfo: %p",info); //this will give "(nil)" or the correct
                               address, alternating
  ...
}

gboolean time_handler (GtkWidget *draw_area)
{
  if ((!GTK_IS_WIDGET(draw_area)) || (!gtk_widget_get_window (draw_area)))
    return FALSE;

  gtk_widget_queue_draw(draw_area);


  return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  ...
  prog_info *info;

  info =(prog_info *) calloc (1,sizeof(prog_info));

  ...

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(draw_area), "draw", G_CALLBACK(on_draw_event), info);

  g_timeout_add (10, (GSourceFunc) time_handler, draw_area);


  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
  gtk_main();
  return 0;
}
```

---

## Solved

Had two different ***g_signal_connect***, one of which was ruining everything.

Comment: your code seems to be working fine for me and it doesn't seem like there is any problem in your code ...try printing the the pointers address before g_signal_connect , gtk_widget_show and gtk_main ..this might help you get an idea as to where the problem is occurring ..... just to be safe you are calling this in your code right "gtk_init(&argc, &argv);"?

Comment: @SivaGuru I did that and I found out that "on_draw_event" was being called two different times. Looked around, and there was another "g_signal_connect" with the wrong arguments. Oh well, thanks.